# How does the aggro system work?

Tags: warframe

I'm wondering how the aggro system works in Warframe.

I want to play as a tank (E.g. Rhino), but most of the time the enemies just attack the other warframes.

Is there a way to force enemies to focus you, otherwise the tank roles are just useless (at least for Rhino)?

Comment: There isn't really a way to pull aggro in the general MMO sense. Enemies typically attack whoever is closer/whoever is dealing the most damage to them. Rhinos iron skin makes him super effective in reviving teammmates in combat, grabbing objectives (eg: life pods in survival), and buffing teammates with his third ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to get fire away from your teammates is to use some niche Warframe skills.

- Excalibur's Radial Blind makes enemies blind and open for finisher attacks
- Loki's Radial Disarm makes enemies drop their weapons (and, in so, decrease their lethality)
- Ash's Smoke Bomb renders him invisible and makes enemies stagger
- Rhino's Stomp makes enemies take damage and float midair for a considerable duration (great to revive other frames!)
- Nyx's Mind Control and Chaos make enemies divert their fire to mind controlled enemies

And so on.

If you are willing to draw attention **TO YOURSELF** (as a taunt), there isn't any specific Warframe skill that does that (aside, maybe, from **Loki's Decoy**, but he's not a tank!  and that isn't really effective!).

You can either **jump headfirst into a fight** making noise (enemies will fire at you with high priority) or be equipped with a **Djinn sentinel** which DOES have a draw fire ability! The only drawback is that you can't directly command it, the attraction radius isn't that wide and you might have your sentinel burst into pieces from enemy fire! (Djinn is also **absolutely expensive** to make!!)

I recommend experimenting with the options offered and generate your own tactics for saving your teammates!

Anyone can be trigger happy ninja, but only some can become the Gods of Life and Death themselves ^^ haha.

Answer (score 2):

Warframe isn't like any other mmo, and it's not like WoW. In warframe there is no tank role, as you will find out that with level 30-40 enemies a warframe is pretty squishy, even rhino. While playing this game all you need to focus on is damage output. Rhino's "Iron Skin" only helps on reviving allies, don't bother upgrading mods like elemental resistance etc, upgrading "Vitality" and "Redirection" and perhaps even "Vigor" is enough.

Comment: I second that the best defense is offense in Warframe. Almost all groups doing long runs I've come across relied mostly on cheesiest and riddiculously broken max damage tactics (say, Ash + melee with crit stats + combo elongation mod + Focus with 4 energy per second).

Comment: Crowd control + damage is the way to go.  Nova + Ember, for example.